# wp_editor: How to load wp_editor on demand using jQuery?

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I am trying to load wp_editor on demand using jquery/javascript.

Somehow I got success using following code  but it does not save changed data in the  element.

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, textarea_id);
```

I'll really appreicate any contribution.

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is here but it may be easier to throw [`wp_eidtor()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) into a `<div>` and show / hide it via JS rather than trying to load an entire editor with JS.